# Highlight error syntax in Visual Studio Code C++ extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have the Visual Studio Code C++ extensions to check syntax error? For example, the below error syntax would be highlighted.

```
std::vectorr vec;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**.  The Microsoft [C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) extension checks for and indicates syntax errors, among other things.  Example:

[image: Screenshot of indicated syntax error]

The red squiggly line is always there, while the popup appears on mouse hover.

I recommend going through the [Getting Started with C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) tutorial for VSCode to make sure you've got everything configured right.