# Enable error highlight in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm recently using Visual Studio Code for C++ programming and i have an error in my code but, i will like VS Code to highlight it
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1gon.png)

Comment: What OS? You need to install actual C++ libraries and the C/C++ extension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490584/highlight-error-syntax-in-visual-studio-code-c-extensions Check this.

Answer (score 7):

The solution's pretty simple actually. Before that make sure that you're in a C++ file. Then, go to the command palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) and search for "error." Click on the "Enable Error Squiggles" option. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install at least one extension

- [C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) for Visual Studio Code

Follow the instructions specific for your compiler and you will get highlighted error. For example if you wish Microsoft compilers [Configure VS Code for Microsoft C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) you will get

[image]

Comment: Intellisense extension is not needed. Evidenced by the fact that the page you link is not to an extension.

Comment: @sweenish Thanks. Updated. As I remember IntelliSense was an extension in the earlier versions of VS Code.