# Visual Studio Code is not highlighting compile errors in my code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm new to visual studio code but whenever I type some code it never showing the deadline syntax error so whenever there is a problem I have to look through every line of code to find something as simple as upper case B instead of a lower case b, I can purposefully make an error like not terminating a line of code with a ';' and it won't show any error or tell me anything at all, I've looked everywhere and I can't find a fix for it PLS Help it's driving me crazy

Comment: I see the title was changed during the edit. @Dubbo28 Which visual studio do you use? The usual Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? (Is the icon blue or purple? :) )

Answer (score 0):

The place you should usually take a look for the errors is the errors window that can be opened from "View" -> "Error List" (or with a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>).
Also if you'd like to get more suggestions, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and type "Intellicode suggestions".
For even more errors and warnings, you can consider installing some of the Roslyn analysers.
Note: And you'll still have to use "Errors List" window for the errors.

UPDATE:
To do the same on Visual Studio Code just navigate to "View" -> "Appearance" -> "Show Panel" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>).  And then open the "Problems" tab.
Alternatively you can click on the error icon on the left side of the statusbar.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path to the root folder of your project is the *absolute path* to it.

It seems that VS code doesn't support symbolic links too well.
For example, if your project is in

```
/home/user/projects/my_project
```

and there is a link, say

```
/home/user/intersting_things/my_project --> /home/user/projects/my_project
```

then you should use the absolute path (`/home/user/projects/my_project`) when you create the "target" for your project in the explorer or remote explorer.

Otherwise, VS code won't be able to tell that the errors it sees in, e.g.,

```
/home/user/projects/my_project/foo.java
```

have anything to do with what you are editing in

```
/home/user/intersting_things/my_project/foo.java
```

Comment: Another requirement is for you to enable error squiggles. For me they were enabled by default, but it's apparently possible to disable them by accident.
Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61166385/enable-error-highlight-in-visual-studio-code